# How to get the coordinates of a particular side of THREE.js Geometry?

Tags: three.js

I have a situation where I need to find the exact coordinates, preferably in screen space (DOM coordinates), of a particular side of a Geometry. For example, for a `BoxGeometry`, there are two `faces` that define one side of the `BoxGeometry`. How would you get the coordinates of the center of a particular side (e.g. top of the box) that is composed of two faces? Or even the center of a particular face on a given side?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question. **1)** I think you want to get the center point of a face (triangle), or a collection of faces (what you call a "side" of your cube). That involves being able to define what a constitutes a collection of faces, and how you compute that center point. **2)** Converting from a 3D point to a 2D (screen space) point has been answered a lot of times.

Comment: I think the first part of the question is how to determine the position (preferably in screen space) of a given face on a Geometry. The second part would be building upon this notion on determining the position of the side of a BoxGeometry that is composed of two faces. @TheJim01